# Resharper: Possible null assignment to entity marked with notnull attribute

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I get this warning on `response.GetResponseStream()`
How should I handle this?

```
// Get response  
using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    // Get the response stream  
    if (response != null)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return responseString;
    }
}
```

**For clarity based on some answers misinterpreting**:

This line is **not** where the warning is occurring:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
```

This line **is** where the warning is occurring:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: @Uwe Resharper doesn't know how to "fix it"

Comment: @katit In my ReSharper (Version 6) it suggests to check for `null` in similar situations.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

I suspect `StreamReader` constructor's parameter has a `notnull` attribute. Try the following:

```
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (stream == null)
  // throw an exception
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

Comment: In modern C#, simply use `var reader = new StreamReader(response?.GetResponseStream() ?? Stream.Null);` to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 6):

Try shortening your code and wrapping disposable resources in `using` statements:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

or even further:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    return client.DownloadString("http://foo.bar.com/")
}
```

Comment: I don't know `C#` much but would `using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))` not get the same resharper warning?

Answer (score 1):

If the `response` object is of type `HttpWebRequest`, then response will always be of type `HttpWebResponse`. If it's not, then it never will be.

Either you're testing this at the wrong place (why call `.GetResponse()` if you could be passed another class derived by `WebRequest` just to throw away the results) or testing unnecessary with no effect.

I'm guessing resharper is worrying about that, despite the test for null below it. I'd go for either a direct cast:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using(var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
  return reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Or, considering you aren't using any members of `HttpWebResponse` that isn't derived from `WebResponse`, no cast at all:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using(var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
  return reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use C#'s [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) to get rid of the warning:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(response?.GetResponseStream());
```

It is a syntactic sugar to avoid writing code for checking null value of a reference at runtime. Internally this code is equivalent to :

```
var reader = new StreamReader(response != null ? response.GetResponseStream() : null);
```