# ReSharper shows possible null assignment on Value for generic Collection

Tags: c#, generics, collections, resharper

I'm using a `Dictionary<string, string>` and add an item with a null value (in my real situation it's a variable).

```
var testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
testDictionary.Add("Test", null);
```

This leads to warning “Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute”.
[image: Possible 'null' assignment]

If I let ReSharper convert it to a Collection Initializer, it doesn’t show any warnings.

```
var testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Test", null}};
```

So, is it true that the Value of a Dictionary is marked with ‘NotNull’ attribute? Or is something else going on?

Edit: This question is not so much different from [Resharper: Possible null assignment to entity marked with notnull attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979008), but the answers on my question are different (it was a bug in R#, and adding null elements to a collection is not a good idea).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resharper: Possible null assignment to entity marked with notnull attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979008/resharper-possible-null-assignment-to-entity-marked-with-notnull-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [a bug, fixed in 6.0](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-207297).

So yes, something else **is** going on - you need to upgrade your R# ;)

Comment: It's an interesting bug. How could ReSharper think the entity was marked with a `NotNull` attribute if it isn't? Anyway, you were right.

Comment: I think the external annotations for the BCL might at one time have been produced manually, so it could just be a simple data error there.

Answer (score 7):

In general it's a bad practice to put `null` elements into a collection.  The overwhelming majority of code which consumes a collection assumes that values in the collection aren't `null`.  If `null` is a valid collection element it really complicates all consumption code.

For example, you essentially need to write

```
foreach (var cur in theCollection) {
  if (cur.Value == null) {
    continue;
  }
  ...
}
```

For this specific case it simply looks like R# is missing the collection initializer case.  It's definitely unexpected for `null` to be in a collection.

Instead of `null` why not use `String.Empty`?

Comment: Yes, but only "in general". Using `null` values is not disallowed or implausible.

Comment: Indeed, Henk.  There's a very real logical difference between string.empty and null.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it's certainly allowed but I'd say it's also just as unexpected. Putting null in a collection violates the "don't surprise your users" rule IMHO.

Comment: +1. [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) is one option when refactoring the design.

Comment: Ok, I can see why it's considered bad practice. But does or doesn't the Value have a `notnull` attribute?

Comment: +1 for explaining why it's generally a bad idea to put `null` values into a Collection. But I feel Aakash's answer better answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper faulty. You can edit use the menu to Inspect Options for "Possible Null..." and change it to Do Not Show if you want to disable the warning.

The code is perfectly fine, although I can't imagine why you would want to add null (usually points at bad design/algorithm, where there is a cleaner way to do it).