# Possible null assignment to entity marked with notnull attribute

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I get this warning on `request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()` How should I handle this?

```
public void GetUserList(string url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    string response;

    using (var stream = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        response = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }

    response = DelimiterStrings.Aggregate(response, (current, delim) => current.Replace(delim, "\n"));

    foreach (var line in response.Split(DelimiterChars))
    {
        MainWindow.UserList.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Resharper doesn't know how to "fix it"

Comment: you would first have to assign it to a new variable, check it on null and then assign it to the reader

Comment: the problem is, if - url response 404 - row enter on exception - how to fix ?

Comment: That would appear to be a different question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resharper: Possible null assignment to entity marked with notnull attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979008/resharper-possible-null-assignment-to-entity-marked-with-notnull-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like in the comment stated, first assign the response stream and check it for null, like so:

```
public void GetUserList(string url)
{
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  var responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
  if (responseStream != null)
  {
    string response;
    using (var stream = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
      response = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }
    response = DelimiterStrings.Aggregate(response, (current, delim) => current.Replace(delim, "\n"));
    foreach (var line in response.Split(DelimiterChars))
    {
      MainWindow.UserList.Add(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate it out:

```
var sourceStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
Contract.Assume(sourceStream != null); // Let Resharper know it can't be null.

using (var stream = new StreamReader(sourceStream))
```

This has the advantage of both documenting AND checking your assumptions!

Comment: You're also assuming that the asker is using Code Contracts :)

Comment: You mean people don't? Blimey! ;) Of course, they could just do `Trace.Assert(sourceStream != null)` instead.